# Grabbing the information from a r.text

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm making a little program that will compare ranks in a game called osu. 
I'm a beginner coder and I'm kind of stuck at the moment at where to go from here, I know/think I will convert the json data into a dict in python and then pull the specific information I need and compare the two users ranks?

Sorry I have only been coding for about 3-4 weeks on my own time now, and I wanted to go ahead and get started on my first small little big project for me.

Here is the git for the game/api I am using 
https://github.com/ppy/osu-api/wiki

My Current Code:

```
import requests
import json


print('Please Enter Usernames to Compare')

payload = {'k': 'myapikey', 'u': input()}
r = requests.get('https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_user', params=payload)

print(r.text)

data = json.loads(r.text)
```

This is what the information looks like when I type in the username 
that I want to grab information from:

```
[
  {
    "user_id": "14376563",
    "username": "kaidwards",
    "join_date": "2019-05-01 01:48:05",
    "count300": "92149",
    "count100": "21750",
    "count50": "3790",
    "playcount": "818",
    "ranked_score": "72307846",
    "total_score": "209966595",
    "pp_rank": "627326",
    "level": "31.8303",
    "pp_raw": "308.758",
    "accuracy": "89.91222381591797",
    "count_rank_ss": "0",
    "count_rank_ssh": "0",
    "count_rank_s": "6",
    "count_rank_sh": "0",
    "count_rank_a": "15",
    "country": "US",
    "total_seconds_played": "58234",
    "pp_country_rank": "97990",
    "events": [
      {
        "display_html": "<img src='/images/S_small.png'/> <b><a href='/u/14376563'>kaidwards</a></b> achieved rank #583 on <a href='/b/1948011?m=0'>Minase Inori, Hanazawa Kana, Iguchi Yuka, Hayami Saori - One Step [Hard]</a> (osu!)",
        "beatmap_id": "1948011",
        "beatmapset_id": "932314",
        "date": "2019-06-29 07:52:16",
        "epicfactor": "1"
      },
      {
        "display_html": "<img src='/images/B_small.png'/> <b><a href='/u/14376563'>kaidwards</a></b> achieved rank #442 on <a href='/b/1985907?m=0'>Kuba Oms - Sex Is Good [Cherry Blossom's Hard]</a> (osu!)",
        "beatmap_id": "1985907",
        "beatmapset_id": "935772",
        "date": "2019-06-29 07:40:31",
        "epicfactor": "1"
      },
      {
        "display_html": "<b><a href='/u/14376563'>kaidwards</a></b> unlocked the \"<b>Challenge Accepted</b>\" medal!",
        "beatmap_id": "0",
        "beatmapset_id": "0",
        "date": "2019-06-29 07:08:11",
        "epicfactor": "4"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to grab the information from the r.text.

The specific thing I need to grab is `pp_rank":"627326`.

I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is a `dictionary` datatype. The values of each of its keys (such as 'pp_rank' or 'level') can be accessed via `data['pp_rank']` or `data['level']`. For example:

```py
>>> data['pp_rank']
627326
```

For more reference on the `dictionary` datatype in Python-3.x, see [Python's data structures documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Comment: Awesome yeah thanks for the help! ```player = r.json()[0]
print(player["pp_country_rank"])``` is what I ended up using